# How to prevent GitLab CI/CD from deleting the whole build

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I'm currently having a frustrating issue.

I have a setup of GitLab CI on a VPS server, which is working completely fine, I have my pipelines running without a problem.

The issue comes after having to redo a pipeline. Each time GitLab deletes the whole folder, where the build is and builds it again to deploy it. My problem is that I have a "uploads" folder, that stores all user content, that was uploaded, and each time I redo a pipeline everything gets deleted from this folder and I obviously need this content, because it's the purpose of the app.

I have tried GitLab CI cache - no luck. I have also tried making a new folder, that isn't in the repository, it deletes it too.

Running my first job looks like so:
[Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9hLC.png)

As you can see there are a lot of lines, that says "Removing ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to persist a folder with local files while integrating CI pipelines, the best approach is to use [Docker data persistency](https://docs.docker.com/storage/), as you'll be able to delete everything from the last build while keeping local files inside your application between your builds, while maintains the ability to start from stretch every time you start a new pipeline.

- [Bind-mount volumes](https://miro.medium.com/max/875/1*bUPk-iAdcofNOSax8uJ1Sg.png)
- [Volumes managed by Docker](https://miro.medium.com/max/875/1*RhW4I9Wrv-3DmQg34jQ4vw.png)

GitLab's CI/CD Documentation provides a short briefing on [how to persist storage between jobs when using Docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#the-persistent-storage) to build your applications.

I'd also like to point out that if you're using Gitlab Runner through SSH, they explicitly state [they do not support caching between builds when using this functionality](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/ssh.html#security). Even when using the standard Shell executor, [they highly discourage saving data to the Builds folder.](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/best_practice/index.html#build-directory) so it can be argued that the best practice approach is to use a bind-mount volume to your host and isolate the application from the user uploaded data.